# Downloadable file from Matrix field

Tags: cartthrob, matrix

I have a product where there are some physical items as well as a downloadable item variation. So, I'm using matrix to to add these variations. The problem that I am having is that the debug statement for the downloadable item states "[Filename] => No download URL was specified."

In my matrix field "product_variations" the column field name is set up as text and named "product_download_url"

I'm setting up my downloadble item using an absolute path: file="root/www/folder/file-name.pdf"

My code for my order info page is:

```
{exp:cartthrob:order_items member_id="CURRENT_USER"}
    <a href="{exp:cartthrob:get_download_link field="[item_options]product_download_url" entry_id="{item:entry_id}" member_id="CURRENT_USER" debug="yes" }">Download</a>
{/exp:cartthrob:order_items}
```

I've tried the code a few ways but I can't seem to get this link to work.

Can anyone help? Many thanks!